# What exactly are the gates in Hodgkin Huxley model?

Tags: neuroscience, action-potential

> Hodgkin & Huxley found that a model with 4 gates in series produces a good fit to the S-shaped curve of the potassium current during the action potential.

Upon reading about the structure of potassium channels on the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_channel#Structure), I still wonder whether it is correct to  imagine these four gates in series as an entrance with four doors in series that all have to be open in order to pass? The article always talks about the potassium channel as being a single tetrameric protein. What are the four variables in the HH-equation that are independent and have to be open (or active if they are not actually gates) in the actual potassium gate? And since there are many potassium gates in a membrane, shouldn't the equation account for the actual number of gates, i.e. the parallel ones?

Comment: The HH model was from long before the structure of the actual gates was known; now the structures are well known. I'd suggest the wikipedia pages on the HH model or the individual channels (voltage gated sodium and potassium channels) which will talk a lot about the gating.

Comment: Looks like you've added a bounty without doing any more of your own reading :(

Comment: I did this by accident. I appreciate your comment and I think it did this question justice. I have another open question which I wanted to be answered, but clicked the wrong one. Is there a way to correct this?

Comment: No, it's not possible to move a bounty (not even a moderator can do anything about that). I think this is still a good question, I just think it would be improved with a bit of focus on what you know and where the gap in understanding is, hence the comment.